# I have to perform "Open In " option for .sav extension file through iOS app

Tags: ios, spss

On iOS devices, the Mail app offers "Open In..." option for attachments. The apps listed have registered their CFBundleDocumentTypes with the OS.Through this I have to open SPSS file(.sav extension) on my app. How would I achieve this?

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>.SAV</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>SPSS</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your app's -Info.plist is the place to add [that key](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-101685-TPXREF107). You can learn about how that plist works in Apple's [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009248-SW1)

Comment: I have edited my question. I am using this plist. But problem is that .sav file is not support by browser, when I tried to open .sav file I am getting error and I am not getting any Open In option for my app, then how would I check it?

Comment: Hi ctrahey Is there any way so that I can open any extension file like when user pinch on attached file he always see mail option.

Comment: The SPSS sav file is a binary format.  You can't open it and read anything useful without software that knows that format.  There are tools available for building such an app, but AFAIK, no one has done that for IOS

Answer (score 0):

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>SPSS</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.item</string>
        </array>
```

By using public.item I have find my solution

Answer (score 0):

```
You are missing some closing XML tags:

    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>a</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>b</string>
            </array>
        **</dict>
    </array>**
```